# draw table in c#.net 2008

Tags: c#, winforms

How to draw the table in c#.net 2008.

or suggest any control as table?

i want to display the data in that table.

help me.

Comment: Web? WinForms? WPF? Printer? Draw _where_?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) component.

Answer (score 0):

Use

- **GridView Control** - if Windows forms
- **DataGridView Control** - if ASP.NET